# Twisted setup Mac OS compiles forever

Tags: macos, clang, twisted

I enter 'pip install Twisted'. Then I get the message
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Twisted ... \
and the \ simply doesn't move.

ps -ef tells me that it tries to compile raiser.c

And there it spent the last hour. I went to gymn and it is still there.

It is a clang compiler. I got it from xcode install. It is version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28).

Comment: Are you install twisted in a virtualenv? If you're not you probably should. I vaguely recall helping people who ran into this issue trying to install on the system python path.

Comment: I think it is the clang version. There seems to be no clear way how to update that.

Comment: Just upgrade to high sierra and xcode latest. Voila